# Accessing all replies to a comment with Graph API

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-graph-api, comments

I'm having trouble accessing **all** replies from a Facebook post using the Graph API.  (A reply is a post made in response to another comment).

For example, going to

https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/472

yields comments in JSON form.  While this JSON document caps the number of commments at 25, one can simply access the remaining comments using the 'paging' and 'next' keys.

Replies, however, appear to be limited to 10 per comment.  Take for instance this snippet of JSON from https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/472

{
            "id": "10150090402026572_14446101", ... ,
            "message": "Excited for the launch of Comments Box this morning!",
            "created_time": "2011-03-01T17:06:45+0000",
            "comments": {
               "data": [...]
            "count": 74
           },

The "comments" : "data" array holds the replies to a comment.  The "count" variable below that indicates how many replies there are.

Is there any way to access all replies on a comment?

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

If you add:

```
&limit=100
```

to the end of the url: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/472

It will display 100 comments, just change the 100 to whatever the count is to display all comments.

Comment: I'm looking for replies to comments.  A reply is a nested record inside of a comment.  This is just displaying 100 comments.